# Change the Background Color for the footer in section

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to change the background color for the footer in the section view.
Set the background color to white.

[image]

I have tried following procedures, none of them worked out.

1. Added code in `viewDidLoad()`

   ```
   let HEADER_HEIGHT = 100
   tableView.tableHeaderView?.frame.size = CGSize(width:
   tableView.frame.width, height: CGFloat(HEADER_HEIGHT)).
   ```
2. `view.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white in willDisplayHeaderView()`
3. changed the color in xib file
4. `heightForFooterInSection`

   ```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
       if section > 1 {
           return 10
       }
       return 0
   }
   ```

Please provide me input on this issue.

Comment: Can you add the full code of view for footer in section method?

Comment: In your picture, what part is the section footer?

Comment: Grey Space is the footer

Comment: rajtharan-g - override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayFooterView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
      
    } The method deprecated .Are you infer this method

Comment: Is this a `UITableViewController` or a `UIViewController` with a table view added? Does the table view fill the screen? Are you implementing the `viewForFooterInSection` method?

Comment: You can use -           (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView     viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // update sectionFooterView.text    
    return sectionFooterView;
}

Comment: set tableView.tableFooterView = UIView() or using multiple sections then implement viewForFooterInSection method and return view with white background.

Answer (score 0):

Primary Issue was Scrolling  headers
So ,I have  changed to Plain to Group. There is extra gray space.
I want to remove the gray space.

Now I am again changed to Group to Plain. Fix the extra gray space.
Fix for Scroll header.
I have added below line in the viewDidLoad()
  self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false